# Please help identify LEGO Batman vehicle

Tags: set-identification

I'm trying to identify the set that this partial Batman vehicle belongs to. I believe the front center piece is part # 4623524 Roof tile 6x10, but all of the sets that contain that part don't seem to match the rest of the pieces.

[image: batman vehicle]

Here is the bottom front of the boat as it has an unusual shape that I can't find:

[image: batman vehicle bottom curve]

Answer (score 8):

It appears to actually be an Iron Man set, with the dark green #4623524 piece swapped out for the same piece in black from a Batman set.

The base is [76006-1 Iron Man: Extremis Sea Port Battle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76006-1)

[image: Iron Man set picture]

Based on the 1x2 slope piece with the Batman symbol, the #4623524 piece likely comes from [76000-1 Arctic Batman vs. Mr. Freeze: Aquaman on Ice](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76000-1)

[image: Batman set picture]